# Left join on two data tables of 2 million rows each

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to do a left join on 2 data table with 2 million rows each and R is crashing due to memory issue. I am using the join function from plyr.

Is there any solution available on the same

Comment: Have you tried the `left_join` from `dplyr`

Comment: Or doing a `data.table` join?

Comment: Or if data.table fails, you could look at the RSQLite package.

Comment: Please see: [*How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: I tried the left_join from dplyr and the same memory issue came.When i tried the data.table join, I got the below error
Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical limit). Very likely misspecified join. Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation.

Comment: The data is in the workspace. I'm not sure how RSQLite will help.

Comment: Write the tables to the database, then do the join, then pull out what you need.

Comment: Based on the error it sounds like there are quite a few duplicate values in the keys you are trying to join on. Are you really expecting 2 billion + rows?

Comment: There are some  duplicates in the IDs but they cannot be removed. They are required for the computation. Yes I am expecting 2 billion + rows since the input has 2 billion + rows. The fix should be within the code and not database dependent.

Comment: when i tried the left_join from dplyr, i got the following error.
Error in left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y) : 
  std::bad_alloc
Any suggestions?